# How to view data in business model and mapping layer in OBIEE 12c?

Tags: obiee

I'm trying to view data in business model level, since we have done data transformation in business model, how view the data in business model as we see in physical model.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You model things, then you expose them through Subject Areas which you then use in the presentation server - Answers or DV.